# Enable SSLV3 request in libcurl 7.52.1

Tags: linux, debian, curl, openssl, ssl

I am using libcurl 7.52.1 to send http request so far I have successfully tried to send TLS request down to TLSV1.0. I need to send SSLV3 requests how can I enable SSLV3 request on my current libcurl version? The reason that I am doing this is that I am using Debian etch which has openssl installed that support only SSL request upto SSLV3. So I want to configure my code with this configuration.

Comment: Recent libcurl versions have no code anymore to support SSLv3. What you ask is not possible, only using an older libcurl version.

Comment: Can I enable TLSV1.2 on libcurl V7.15.5.